# Root - failed filling branch : memory-resident tree

Tags: c++, root-framework

I am trying to merge trees doing :

```
string filename_;
TList *list = new TList;

///Loop on all .root output files
for (int i = 1; i < 13; ++i) {
  string filename_ = "file_";
  string file_extension = ".root";
  stringstream ss;
  ss << i;
  string str = ss.str();
  filename_ = filename_+str+file_extension;
  const char* c_filename = filename_.c_str();
  TFile *file_adress = TFile::Open(c_filename);
  TTree *tree_adress = (TTree*)file_adress->Get("pulses");
  list->Add(tree_adress);
}

// Output tree:
TTree *TPulses = TTree::MergeTrees(list);
```

But I am getting this error, which is quietly explicite :

```
Error in <TTree::Fill>: Failed filling branch:pulses.pulse_time, nbytes=-1, entry=115710
 This error is symptomatic of a Tree created as a memory-resident Tree
 Instead of doing:
    TTree *T = new TTree(...)
    TFile *f = new TFile(...)
 you should do:
    TFile *f = new TFile(...)
    TTree *T = new TTree(...)
```

But I am creating the TFile before the TTree in the for loop, so I don't understand.
Does someone have an idea ?

Comment: What language are you writing in? Please tag appropriately. The tag "root" is for *nix administrator issues.

Comment: Ok thank you, I am writting in C++, in the Root framework

Comment: unrelated to your problem, but I'd shorten to `TFile::Open(Form("file_%d.root",i));` to shorten all that juggeling with std::string, c-string, stringstream. [From doc](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/TString_8cxx.html#a3b5b568376e617c4b5d6a91c7a2b675a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you're seeing is from a `TTree` that you're writing to. As far as I understand your code, the `TFile *file_adress` and `TTree *tree_adress` are opened for reading and you write to `TTree *TPulses`. I don't see the default setting for `TFile::Open` (if it's `READ` for read-only or `update` for manipulating contents) but from your output I claim `TPulses` does not get created in the last file you open, but rather in RAM and you run out of that ([see docs](https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTTree.html#a8d4212a53f96f9c3bcbd384892d3bd81)). A common pattern would be to create an output file before creating `TPulses`:

```
TFile* outputfile = TFile::Open("output.root", "recreate");
TTree* TPulses = TTree::MergeTrees(list);
// ...
TPulses->Write();
outputfile->Close();
delete outputfile;
```